# %Net.FtpSession Trace Mask method

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

In %Net.SSH.Session there is a method settraceMask and that will create a wireshark cap file for help with troubleshooting a connection. I dont see any class in Net.FtpSession that can be used for troubleshooting. Is there a different method that I should use?